# WPF Data Binding TooWay XAML to C# and C# to XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I have XAML code:

```
<TextBox Name="textBoxMask1"/>
<TextBox Name="textBoxMask2"/>
<TextBox Name="textBoxMask3"/>
...
<TextBox Name="textBoxMask9"/>
```

and class in C#:

```
private static string mask1;
public static string Mask1
{
    get { return mask1; }
    set { mask1 = value; }
}

private static string mask2;
public static string Mask2
{
    get { return mask2; }
    set { mask2 = value; }
}

private static string mask3;
public static string Mask3
{
    get { return mask3; }
    set { mask3 = value; }
}
....
private static string mask9;
public static string Mask9
{
    get { return mask9; }
    set { mask9 = value; }
}
```

And I want to bind these TextBoxes with Properties -> textBoxMask1 with Mask1 etc.
Earlier I did this by TextChanged, but I want to make Binding. TooWay Binding, because I want to predefine Mask1, Mask2, Mask3, ..., Mask9 in another C# class, and maybe later change these values - also in some C# code - and I want my changes, to be visible in layout (XAML) and in C# code - so ex. changing Property Mask1 from C# will change Text in TextBox textBoxMask1, and changing Text in textBoxMask1 will change Property Mask1.
I don't understand, how to make connection (binding) between objects XAML and C#.

Comment: Have you read this article? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For a normal Binding you don't need your properties to be static, just public. Here an example:

C# code (for one property)

```
private string mask1;
public string Mask1
{
    get { return mask1; }
    set 
        { 
           mask2 = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("Mask1");
        }
}
```

It's really important for the binding that the class containing the properties implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and that you raise the corresponding event in the setter of each property. Another option is to make all properties DependecyProperty, but it is usually overkill.

As for the XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="textBoxMask1" Text="{Binding Mask1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

(TwoWay Binding is the default for the Text property, but it does not hurt to put it explicitly).

Just make sure that the DataContext of the object containing your TexBoxes (usually an UserControl) is set to a valid instance of your C# class.

By the way, this is a very basic question, that's why you got a negative vote and no answers before mine. What is expected is that you ask a question that poses a real problem for you, with a very specific answer, not something like "teach me how to do this".

If this answers your question don't forget to mark it as answer (the "tick" mark on the top left). A vote up would be also appreciated.

Hope it helps, regards.